# How do we sign these deb packages

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb, docker-image, mariasql

I have followed this link and created deb packages for Maria DB.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/building-mariadb-on-ubuntu/

I have the following deb files generated and I need to sign them and create a docker image . Any pointers for this process.

libmariadb-dev-compat_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

libmariadb-dev-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

libmariadb-dev_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

libmariadb3-compat_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

libmariadb3-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

libmariadb3_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

libmariadbclient18_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

libmariadbd-dev_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

libmariadbd19-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

libmariadbd19_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

libmysqlclient18_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

mariadb-10.3_10.3.6+maria~artful.dsc

mariadb-10.3_10.3.6+maria~artful.tar.xz

mariadb-10.3_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.buildinfo

mariadb-10.3_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.changes

mariadb-backup-10.3-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

mariadb-backup-10.3_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

mariadb-client-10.3-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

mariadb-client-10.3_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

mariadb-client-core-10.3-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

mariadb-client-core-10.3_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

mariadb-client_10.3.6+maria~artful_all.deb

mariadb-common_10.3.6+maria~artful_all.deb

mariadb-plugin-aws-key-management-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

mariadb-plugin-aws-key-management_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

mariadb-plugin-connect-dbgsym_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.ddeb

mariadb-plugin-connect_10.3.6+maria~artful_amd64.deb

Thanks,
B

Comment: any pointers for signing these packages ?.

Comment: Did you try this: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/10/28/howto-gpg-sign-verify-deb-packages-apt-repositories/ ?